# Is there a way to combine values from a single field that will always follow the sequence to create all the movements per ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In SQL, I have a table that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEcpr.png)

I wanted to combine the values from 'Value_New' per 'id_Parent_Record' according to the 'Seq_Number' which means it should always starts from 1.

As an example, 637454609993200 has total of 4 movements for 'Field_Changed' = 'Task_Workflow' .

Expected output should be exactly like this:

Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement

This is the code where I am currently at:

```
select ac."id_Parent_Record"
,ac."Field_Changed"
,ac."Value_Previous"
,ac."Value_New"
,ac."Changed_Date" 
,row_number() over (partition by "id_Parent_Record", "Field_Changed"  order by "Changed_Date" asc) as "Seq_Number"
from public.api_changelog ac
where ac."Field_Changed" IN ('_id_Matter','Task_Workflow')
and ac."id_Parent_Record" = '637454609993200';
```

Expected output should have a new field named 'Transitions' which values should look like this per row for the account 637454609993200, which Field_Change is equal to Task_Workflow:

**Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement**

Comment: Who made this database?  Is it for learning or professional?  You are asking something a data warehouse would typically do.  If you look up books written by Ralph Kimball, you will know what I mean.  Read about slowly changing dimensions.  Rather than writing SQL to perform these tasks, a data warehouse moves data on a regular basis to type 2 tables or type 3 tables or type 6 tables, etc.. and tasks like this are usually performed on the historical data in these tables because it shows how each record changed overtime.

Comment: This is a good question, but I'm just wondering if building a data warehouse would serve a better purpose for what you are doing here.  And the query becomes MUCH more simple!

Comment: The id_Parent_Record would be the natural key in a DW table.  Normally each field in the upstream operational database (where the natural key is unique for each record) has it's own column in a dimension table and the old and new values can be seen easily for each surrogate record.  It looks like you have a soft coded dimension table where the old and new value are explicit columns in one record rather than being one column for two records of the same natural key.  Same concept, but a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STRING_AGG` function should be able to accomplish this.

Each `Value_New` should be delimited by `' -> '` and it should be ordered by the `Changed_Date` field. A `GROUP BY` will need to be included.

```sql
select ac."id_Parent_Record"
,ac."Field_Changed"
, STRING_AGG(ac."Value_New", ' -> ' ORDER BY ac."Changed_Date" asc) AS "Transitions"
from public.api_changelog ac
where ac."Field_Changed" IN ('_id_Matter','Task_Workflow')
and ac."id_Parent_Record" = '637454609993200'
GROUP BY ac."id_Parent_Record"
,ac."Field_Changed"
;
```

Output:

| id_Parent_Record | Field_Changed | Transitions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637454609993200 | _id_Matter | 637417579791350 |
| 637454609993200 | Task_Workflow | Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement |

A CTE could be used to rejoin the table back to the original result set

```sql
WITH transitions AS (
    select ac."id_Parent_Record"
    ,ac."Field_Changed"
    , STRING_AGG(ac."Value_New", ' -> ' ORDER BY ac."Changed_Date" asc) AS "Transitions"
    from public.api_changelog ac
    where ac."Field_Changed" IN ('_id_Matter','Task_Workflow')
    and ac."id_Parent_Record" = '637454609993200'
    GROUP BY ac."id_Parent_Record"
    ,ac."Field_Changed"
)

select ac."id_Parent_Record"
,ac."Field_Changed"
,ac."Value_Previous"
,ac."Value_New"
,ac."Changed_Date" 
, t."Transitions"
from public.api_changelog ac
INNER JOIN transitions t
    ON ac."id_Parent_Record" = t."id_Parent_Record"
    AND ac."Field_Changed" = t."Field_Changed"
;
```

| id_Parent_Record | Field_Changed | Value_Previous | Value_New | Changed_Date | Transitions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637454609993200 | _id_Matter |  | 637417579791350 | 2021-01-07 | 637417579791350 |
| 637454609993200 | Task_Workflow |  | Initial Referral | 2021-01-05 | Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement |
| 637454609993200 | Task_Workflow | Initial Referral | IRU | 2021-01-06 | Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement |
| 637454609993200 | Task_Workflow | IRU | Adjustment Approved | 2021-03-26 | Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement |
| 637454609993200 | Task_Workflow | Adjustment Approved | Settlement | 2021-06-02 | Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement |

Comment: Hi, this is almost similar to what i am expecting. 

Is it possible to have that output while still having the same number of rows?

So Initial Referral -> IRU -> Adjustment Approved -> Settlement would appear in all of the rows in that specific account from a more granular dataset.

Comment: @plae - I've updated the answer to include a join back to the original table.

Comment: insane sql skills. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a typical data warehouse dimension table, the data would look like this.  I'm not posting as an answer for you to accept, but I'm showing how it simplifies your query.  No query needed.

> surr_key (surrogate key) = Seq_Number

> nat_key (natural key) = id_Parent_Record

```
surr_key   nat_key   Task_Workflow         _id_Matter    Transition
1          200       Initial Referral      350           Initial Referral
2          200       IRU                   350           Initial Referral > IRU
3          200       Adjustment Approved   350           Initial Referral > IRU > Adjustment Approved
4          200       Settlement            350           Initial Referral > IRU > Adjustment Approved > Settlement
```

One drawback from this data model compared to your data model is that when a  column changes, a new column is added or a column is deleted in the operational database (upstream), the dimension table above would need to be rebuilt and data moved over with the new DDL.